# Why does my django development server keep responding with 403, how do I allow POST?

Tags: android, django, post

So I have a django development server that I want to be the backend for my android app. For the time being, its I am just running the development server on my local machine.

I've been able to successfully retrieve data from the server, but I am now trying to `POST` data to the server through a JSON object, however I keep getting error code 403 in response. The method in my `views.py` file doesn't even get called, it just automatically response with 403. Heres what the server response looks like in the terminal.

```
 [28/Nov/2011 17:58:40] "POST /createUser/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2326
```

Here is the url in my urls.py

```
 url(r'^createUser/$', 'mydb.views.createUser'),
```

But I am always getting this 403 error, does anyone know why?

Possibly also important:

when I remove `django.contrib.auth` and `django.contrib.contenttypes` from `INSTALLED_APPS` I get a different print out from the server in the terminal: (error code 500 instead)

```
 [28/Nov/2011 17:32:31] "POST /createUser/ HTTP/1.1" 500 82471
```

So I am thinking there is some sort of permissions issue going on.

Comment: Do you have a CSRF token?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Comment: Turn debugging on and try load the view in the browser normally (i.e. visit the URL)

Comment: hmm, it does actually go into the method. The server prints this to terminal: `[28/Nov/2011 18:34:56] "GET /createUser/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8`

Comment: I don't really even know what a CSRF token is, so I don't think so, ill read that link. Are they required? I would really just like to make everything public while I develop the app, and then worry about the server side after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick fix, try adding @csrf_exempt decorator to the view:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def createUser(request):
```

That said, for a back end API, definitely read up on CSRF

Comment: What if I don't want to exempt csrf.

Answer (score 0):

I read the following link about CSRF tokens: docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf

Then I turned off middleware since I am just on the localhost for the time being.